# Moving a Linux binary

Tags: linux

Is it safe to move a binary from `/sbin` to `/usr/sbin`. When I installed ZFS for linux it placed the binaries in /sbin, but when I type `zpool list` it says the binary is it not in `/usr/sbin`. Is it okay to move them? Is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it's safe, as long as you don't have any programs that use the binary from /sbin (often they just search $PATH), but to be save, you'll want to [symlink](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln) it:

```
mv /sbin/<your binary> /usr/sbin/
ln -s /usr/sbin/<your binary> /sbin/
```

Comment: Isn't /sbin supposed to be included in $PATH by default?

Comment: It should be. I'm talking about programs that might hard code it in.

Comment: @Solignis: All `sbin` directories are supposed to be in $PATH, but only for root.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe, but you may confuse your package manager. Can can also just use a symlink from /usr/sbin to /sbin.

Comment: sounds like symlinks are the best way to do it. Works for me